# Scheduler module- How is the check for publishing done?

Tags: 7

I just installed the [scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) module and now I was wondering how the check for publising/unpublishing is done. Is it done by a cron task or is a database query executed at every page load or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is executed by the cron. The cron triggers a query to check wether something should be published.
It is a bit contraintuitive though. If your cron runs every hour and you want something published on 22:35 and it is past that time it will be actually published the next time your cron runs. So if your cron runs at 22:30 and 23:30 the publish will be at 23:30.

Comment: This was very very helpful. I had done all the configuration but was thinking why I am not able to get it working.
Great Help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler run as described by reptilex. When it runs, it registers a record in the wathdog table so you can have a look there to be sure everything worked fine.

However this is not very friendly. There's a better way to check this using an undocumented hook of scheduler: [`hook_scheduler_api()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--scheduler--scheduler.module/function/_scheduler_scheduler_api/7).
With this you can write some hook code like this.

```
function mymodule_scheduler_api($node, $action) {
  if ($action == 'publish') {
    $message = 'The content ' . $node->title . ' has been published';
    //Send an email with $message.
    //...
  }
}
```